# Should global css styles be set on the html element or the body element?

Tags: html, css

Sometimes I see people apply global css styles to `html`, sometimes I see them apply them to `body`, with both raw css and javascript.

Are there any differences between the two? Which is the standard to make a global css style? Is there anything I should know when picking between them?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm assuming that "global page styling" here refers to things such as fonts, colors and backgrounds.

Personally, I apply global page styling, for the most part, to `body` and the simple element selectors (`p`, `h1, h2, h3...`, `input`, `img`, etc). These elements are more closely related to the presentation of content of an HTML page to the user.

My rationale for this is simple: the presentational attributes `bgcolor`, `background`, `text`, `topmargin`, `leftmargin` and others were given to the `body` element, not the `html` element. These attributes are now converted to [their respective CSS rules with extremely low precedence in the cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#preshint):

> The UA may choose to honor presentational attributes in an HTML source document. If so, these attributes are translated to the corresponding CSS rules with specificity equal to 0, and are treated as if they were inserted at the start of the author style sheet.

Most if not all implementations I'm aware of will convert these to CSS rules on `body`, based on their HTML equivalents. Others such as `link`, `alink` and `vlink` will become `a:link`, `a:active` and `a:visited` rules respectively.

Of course, it should be noted that CSS itself doesn't really have any semantics to it *per se*, as it's a styling language in itself which is completely separate from the content structure of an HTML document. Although the [introduction to CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html) covers the basics of styling an HTML document, note that the section calls itself non-normative (or informative); this means it doesn't set any hard and fast rules for CSS implementers to follow. Instead, it simply provides information for readers.

That said, certain styles may be applied to `html` to modify viewport behavior. For example, to hide the page scrollbars use:

```css
html {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can also apply rules to both `html` and `body` for interesting effects; see the following questions for details and examples:

- [What's the difference in applying CSS to html, body, and *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187569/whats-the-difference-in-applying-css-to-html-body-and)
- [Applying a background to <html> and/or <body>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body)

Note that `html` is not the viewport; the viewport establishes an initial containing block in which `html` is situated. That initial containing block cannot be targeted with CSS, because in HTML, the root element is `html`.

Note also that, technically, there is no difference between applying properties to `html` and `body` that are inherited by default, such as `font-family` and `color`.

Last but not least, here is an excellent [article](http://phrogz.net/css/htmlvsbody.html) that details the differences between `html` and `body` in terms of CSS. In summary (quoted from its first section):

> - The `html` and `body` elements are distinct block-level entities, in a
>     parent/child relationship.
> - The `html` element's height and width are controlled by the browser window.
> - It is the `html` element which has (by default) `overflow:auto`, causing
>     scrollbars to appear when needed.
> - The body element is (by default) `position:static`, which means that
>     positioned children of it are
>     positioned relative to the `html`
>     element's coordinate system.
> - In almost all modern browsers, the built-in offset from the edge of the
>     page is applied through a `margin` on
>     the `body` element, not `padding` on the
>     `html` element.

As the root element, `html` is more closely associated with the browser viewport than `body` (which is why it says `html` has `overflow: auto` for scrollbars). Note however that the scrollbars are not necessarily generated by the `html` element itself. By default, it's the *viewport* that generates these scrollbars; the values of `overflow` are simply transferred (or *propagated*) between `body`, `html`, and the viewport, depending on which values you set. The details of all this are covered in the CSS2.1 spec, which [says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow):

> UAs must apply the 'overflow' property set on the root element to the viewport. When the root element is an HTML "HTML" element or an XHTML "html" element, and that element has an HTML "BODY" element or an XHTML "body" element as a child, user agents must instead apply the 'overflow' property from the first such child element to the viewport, if the value on the root element is 'visible'. The 'visible' value when used for the viewport must be interpreted as 'auto'. The element from which the value is propagated must have a used value for 'overflow' of 'visible'.

The last bullet point probably has its roots in the aforementioned `topmargin` and `leftmargin` attributes of the `body` element.

Comment: Beat me to it. Also: it should be noted that body functions as a div would, expanding to the contents held inside, whereas html spans the entire viewport.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to style only the content that'll be displayed, targeting the `<body>` element saves the style rules an unnecessary level of cascading.

Is there a reason you'd want to apply styles to the `<title>`, `<meta>`, `<script>` etc... tags? That would happen by targeting `<html>`.