# Fullscreen gradient not working CSS

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

I want to put a gradient background in my website in HTML, but it isn't fullscreen!
My code:

```css
.princip, .body, .html {
width:100%;
height:100%;
 /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffbfbf+0,23538a+100 */
background: rgb(255,191,191); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,191,191,1) 0%, rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,191,191,1) 0%,rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,191,191,1) 0%,rgba(35,83,138,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffbfbf', endColorstr='#23538a',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

There is still a little margin on the sides...

Comment: Have you removed the default `margin` from `<body>`?

Comment: how you do that?

Comment: @Quentin Here’s another one: [CSS: How can I get rid of the default window “padding”? An element set to 100% width doesn't reach the window's borders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4570212/4642212).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is can help you:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```