# Is not changing the body an HTML/CSS standard?

Tags: html, css

Often times I see something like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>
```

Why not just do:

```
<body class="container">
</body>
```

Comment: both are perfectly valid HTML. No standard there. Often, though, if your site is being spit out from a CMS, the CMS often does not allow for touching the BODY tag (most CMSes suck from a code perspective)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are perfectly free to do any of the following:

- add a `class` or `id` attribute to the `body` element;
- directly apply CSS to the `body` element, with or without `class` or `id` attributes; or
- directly apply CSS to the `html` element, although *without* the `class` or `id` attributes and with [some important caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942/should-global-css-styles-be-set-on-the-html-element-or-the-body-element).

Any of these are perfectly legitimate uses of CSS and HTML.

Why `<div id="container"/>`? Through the years, many CSS techniques have employed arbitrary container elements for conceptual simplicity, to avoid certain cross-browser inconsistencies or because they were simply too complex to be achieved otherwise. A couple of more subtle reasons include that in older browsers, one could not apply CSS to the `html` element directly, and there were (and are) certain unusual or restricted properties for those elements—often for [obvious reasons](http://www.mail-archive.com/dev-tech-layout@lists.mozilla.org/msg01520.html). (They were [sometimes described as being "magic"](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2007Mar/0035.html) for this reason.)

These all conspired to create a situation where to achieve almost any moderately complex layout, it was inevitably much easier to just start out with a squeaky-clean container element. Though the practice started as a means to an end it soon became just part of the scenery, and now many developers don't think twice about adding that sprinkling of extra markup.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing that says you can't add a class to the body.

Attaching a class to the body is actually quite common in various CMSes and is very handy for theming or styling specific pages.

From looking at your example, if you just want to use the body as a container, why even bother with the class? There should only be one body element, so just call that in your selector.

Answer (score 1):

Walter, it may make sense if you needed to apply a slightly different subset of styling to a page with a custom body tag.

Using a wrapping div is usually for some presentational reason and make not make sense semantically; if you don't need it for your project, don't use it. Sometimes only using the body tag to contain the page is too inflexible for some layouts, and as Jordan says some old browsers cannot apply CSS to the root element.