# Why target the HTML tag when the BODY tag encapsulates everything visible?

Tags: html, css, document-body

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should global css styles be set on the html element or the body element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942/should-global-css-styles-be-set-on-the-html-element-or-the-body-element)

Why do people target the HTML tag for styling when the BODY tag encapsulates everything visible? Shouldn't the BODY tag then be the main tag to target when targeting the entire page? Any detail would be greatly appreciated.