# CSS - Styling <body> element vs. styling <html> element

Tags: html, css

What are the advantages & disadvantages of styling the `<html>` element instead of the `<body>` element?

I have seen it used in many cases such as in [a full page background image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/#more-3458), or to make an element take up 100% of the view port height.

...but I'm sure there are some limitations. Do you know of any specific browser support issues etc?

Comment: Here's another use: [Sizing fonts with REM units](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem)

Comment: see [What's the difference between applying CSS to html, body, and *?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187569/whats-the-difference-between-applying-css-to-html-body-and) and [Should global css styles be set on the html element or the body element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942/should-global-css-styles-be-set-on-the-html-element-or-the-body-element) - the latter seems to be a closer dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two articles about this very thing:
[How to center and layout pages without a wrapper](http://camendesign.com/code/developpeurs_sans_frontieres)
[Styling HTML and body elements](http://www.sitepoint.com/styling-the-html-and-body-elements/)

Comment: Interesting articles. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An example of this is for a fixed-width body. I use this on [my own site](http://pokefarm.org/) - the light green area is the body and the gradient background is applied to the `html` element.

As far as I am aware there are no browser issues. Maybe in IE5.5 (because I do see problems in Quirks Mode) but aside from that it works just fine.

Comment: Don't really care about IE5, or IE6 for that matter. :)

Comment: Okay, so you're all good :) Style away!