# Should we be applying CSS to <body> vs. <html> elements?

Tags: html, css, semantic-markup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should global css styles be set on the html element or the body element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565942/should-global-css-styles-be-set-on-the-html-element-or-the-body-element)

There's [some really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947541/applying-a-background-to-html-and-or-body) interesting [discussion about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187569/whats-the-difference-in-applying-css-to-html-body-and) applying CSS to `<html>` and `<body>` in order to get some cool effects — like two background images, one transparent (but CSS3 may [render that useless](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/)).

However, for the standard cases, **which element is most appropriate to use for appling page-wide CSS to?**

Perhaps there's even some CSS properties that are better suited to one selector over the other? Thus, split among the two?

(This concerns things like *cross-browser compatibility*, as well as *proper semantics* according to spec.)

And we can also bring the wildcard `* { }` selector into this discussion.

Comment: Related:  [What's the difference in applying CSS to html, body, and *?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7187569)

Comment: @Pekka: That was already linked in the question ;)

Comment: @BoltClock oops, my bad.

Comment: I don't think the universal selector fits within the scope of this question (you can see how hard I'm trying to avoid calling it a discussion...).

Comment: @Baumr: I finished editing my answer (finally). If it answers your question, and you feel that the questions are the same, feel free to flag your question as a duplicate.

Comment: Perfect answer, feel free to link to it as a reply and I can mark it as the solution here? (Don't know what the policy here is.)

Comment: No problem. Questions that are the same as others are typically closed as duplicates with a link to the older question at the very top, rather than having an answer to the earlier question simply linked to newer one at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the W3C recommends that you apply any page-wide styles to the `<body>` element.

Comment: This would be a great answer if it had some sources to go with it.

Comment: @Pekka: I was just going to say :P

Answer (score 1):

Following Verandaguy's answer, http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/011/firstcss.en.html applies the style to the body. It doesn't say why, but, that's what it says.

Comment: That's just an example, though, which is therefore non-normative. That might explain why it doesn't explain why (try saying that 5 times fast). Another tutorial can be found in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html but it's also non-normative.

Answer (score -1):

For creating a site with several pages it is best to use the CSS as an external linked page.  That way each page can have access to it. But for a single page to page, it would be a "cool effect" on some browsers.  But in the same effect other computers might see those effects in a different and less rendered method.  Stick with uses the CSS mostly as an external link, and use style tags only as needed, or leave a note on the page of how and what browser they are supposed to view it on.

Comment: Huh? Seems you misunderstood :P